# INSERT INTO Statement automatically adds thousand separators to java integer starting at 1000k

Tags: java, insert, mariadb

I encountered a weird problem:

I have a column "MaxDealtDamage" which is for instance lower then 1000000 (1000k).
code is like this:

```
class xyz = PlayerData.GetData(player);
xyz.LoginTimes++;
PlayerData.SetData(xyz, player);
```

When it is 1000000 (1000k) or higher this error is beeing send:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.000, `MaxDefense` = 0 WHERE UUID='d839d1f0-ad5b-4922-841c-1d6ee05d9f56'' at line 1

Its behaving like it would try to give him a String containing "4.000.000" but its an integer with the value "4000000" (4000k). For beeing sure the output in runtime is 4000000 I doublechecked it.

Here the query:

> MessageFormat.format("INSERT INTO PlayerData(`UUID`,`VIPExpirationDate`,`IPv4`,`FirstPlayTime`,`LastPlayTime`,`TotalPlayTime`,`TotalLogins`,`MaxDealtDamage`,`MaxDefense`) "
>                       + "VALUES(''{0}'',''{1}'',''{2}'',''{3}'',''{4}'',{5},{6},{7},{8});", data.UUID.toString(), DBDateFormat.format(data.VIPExpirationDate), data.IPv4, DBDateFormat.format(data.FirstPlayTime), DBDateFormat.format(data.LastPlayTime), data.TotalPlayTime, data.TotalLogins, data.MaxDealtDamage, data.MaxDefense);

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageFormat` is not a tool for creating SQL statements. It's a simple utility for building text messages with correct formatting.

You are supposed to use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with bind parameters as explained in the [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) tutorial. JDBC will take care of escaping and formatting the supplied values so they can be received by the database server while preventing [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I should have been thinking about that MessageFormat is only for **text** building.

Comment: Worked pretty well and is even less work, thank you! :)

Comment: @Quantum and is secure, please read about SQL Injection attack

Comment: You are right because this also does escaping as far as I read.